# Unable to read a value which exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am making a library management software. I have a method which gets Book info:

```
public static Book GetInfoAboutBook(string title)
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=" + fileName))
        {
            db.Open();

            Book b = new Book();

            SqliteCommand sqliteCommand = new SqliteCommand
            {
                Connection = db,
                CommandText = "select Title, Author, Publisher, ISBN, Quantity, CoverImageLocation, Tags from MyBooks where Title = '@Title'",
            };

            sqliteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);

            SqliteDataReader query = sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if(query.Read())
            {
                b.Title = query.GetString(0);
                b.Author = query.GetString(1);
                b.Publisher = query.GetString(2);
                b.Quantity = query.GetInt32(3);
                b.CoverImageLocation = query.GetString(4);
                b.Tags = query.GetString(5);
            }

            return b;
        }
    }
```

'b' is never initialized no matter what the input. I made sure all the inputs are actually present in the database. But it does not work. I debugged into this function. query.Read() is never successful. That's how the book object remains null. This is the Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public string CoverImageLocation { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** The title is guaranteed to be unique.

This is the schema of the database:

> CREATE TABLE MyBooks(Title text Primary Key, Author text not null, Publisher text not null, ISBN text not null, Quantity int not null, CoverImageLocation text not null, Tags text not null);

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to make the title as Primary Key, you should add a new column e.g: `Id` or even used the ISBN, which i think is unique.

Comment: I saw many forums which had a discussion about two books with the same ISBN. That's how I decided to make title the primary key @OrelEraki

Comment: Then you should use special generated Id column, because Title is surely not unique in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your SQL:

```
select Title, Author, Publisher, ISBN, Quantity, CoverImageLocation, Tags
from MyBooks where Title = '@Title'
```

That's looking for a book with a title of literally `@Title` - it's *not* looking for the parameter value, because you've got `@Title` in quotes as a text literal. You want SQL of:

```
select Title, Author, Publisher, ISBN, Quantity, CoverImageLocation, Tags
from MyBooks where Title = @Title
```

The difference is right at the end. That SQL will use the `@Title` parameter in the search.